# Getting MySQL thread_id from spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

How to get thread_id of the current DB changes done via spring boot service.

I looked into DataSource but in this, I can not find any thread_id related thing.

I am following one [article of medium.com](https://medium.com/myheritage-engineering/achieving-real-time-analytics-via-change-data-capture-d69ed2ead889).

Here, we are getting DB change logs using Maxwell. Maxwell is generating change logs with DB thread_id in Kafka.

When someone hits any REST endpoint of service, that service uses its logic to modify one insert some records in DB (this change will have some MySQL related `thread_id`), Maxwell pushes message in Kafka related to the modification done in DB, that same service has to make one entry in DB using MySQL Blackhole Engine  which maps DB `thread_id` and Service `request_id`. How can we request to MySQL to get `thread_id`.